# Remove paragraph of lines from file starting with() that ended with()

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is an example of my file blah.log

> Y:\TH2020-0600_1P00392G01_02\1P00392G01_02.obc[30-SEP-20  10:42:47
>
> @30-SEP-20  10:42:51
>
> yhjubad7
>
> q28ed7qai
>
> aiuwdh8
>
> "30-SEP-20  10:43:06
>
> @30-SEP-20  10:43:39      nkdjaw
> adibw
>
> akwudbnawikd
>
> /30-SEP-20  10:43:52      @30-SEP-20  10:43:52     ahuwsd8
>
> 2dhaiubd      98wha98     "30-SEP-20  10:49:39
>
> ]30-SEP-20  11:29:03
>
> Y:\TH2020-0600_1P00392G01_02\1P00392G01_02.obc[01-OCT-20  11:19:08
> ]01-OCT-20  11:26:29

there is a lot more ( like thousands ) lines but i just sum it up

I wanted to remove paragraph of lines that start with '@' and end with '/' ( at the end it some of them is '?' or '!' ) .

and this is my code

```
file = "cpcpk/1P00392G01_02.LOG"
newfile="cpcpk/New_1P00392G01_02.LOG"
new=open(newfile,'w')
with open(file) as input_data:
    # loops through the whole file
    for line in input_data:
        # reset data
        data=[]
        if line.startswith('@'):
            # Skips text before the beginning of the interesting block
            for line in input_data:
                if line.startswith('@'):
                    #write test log in a new file
                    data.append(line)
                    break
            # Reads text until the end of the block:
            for line in input_data:  
                if line.startswith('"'):
                    data.append(line)
                    new.writelines(data)
                    break
                elif line.startswith('/'):
                    break
                elif line.startswith('?'):
                    break
                elif line.startswith('!'):
                    break
                data.append(line)
                
new.close()
```

First problem

When I run it, it did remove it but some of my lines that I want also got remove.

Second problem

If I code it like that the first line and the last few lines also will not be written.

This is the output I desire:

> Y:\TH2020-0600_1P00392G01_02\1P00392G01_02.obc[30-SEP-20  10:42:47
>
> @30-SEP-20  10:42:51
>
> yhjubad7
>
> q28ed7qai
>
> aiuwdh8
>
> "30-SEP-20  10:43:06      @30-SEP-20  10:43:52
> ahuwsd8
>
> 2dhaiubd
>
> 98wha98
>
> "30-SEP-20  10:49:39
>
> ]30-SEP-20  11:29:03
>
> Y:\TH2020-0600_1P00392G01_02\1P00392G01_02.obc[01-OCT-20  11:19:08

What I mean is, if the line start with `@`, for an example `@30-SEP-20 10:42:51`  then it will start to write the lines into a list. Then when the for line loop, loop to a line that starts with `"`, for an example `"30-SEP-20 10:43:06` it will stop the loop and then it will write the list to a new file but if it loop to a line that starts with `/`, for an example `/30-SEP-20 10:43:06` it will stop the loop and reset the list and then start over. Like what I coded. You can see that I have 3 loops. The second and the third loop is to find what I want and what I don't want. Then, the first loop is to repeat the second and third loop.

Comment: There is not one line in your example starting with `@` and ending with `/`

Comment: this is. is at the start of the line

Comment: Please clarify your question to your exact needs. Right now you have 3 answers that got it wrong...

Comment: @30-SEP-20 is the start and "30-SEP-20 is the end. is the end is /-SEP-20 then this will not be written down to new file

Comment: Yes I was able to understand that from your expected output, but as you can see there are 3 answers that didn't understand it that way. Please clarify your question!

Comment: Your question still says *I wanted to remove lines that start with '@' and end with '/'*. Can you see why this is confusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to specify a pattern to detect the lines you want to remove:

```py
import re

with open(file) as input_file, open(newfile, 'w') as new:
    new.write(re.sub(r"@[^@]+/.*\n", "", input_file.read())
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AgrKTN/1/)

---

If the file is too big and you can't read it all at once you can do something like:

```py
buff = []
with open(file) as input_file, open(newfile, 'w') as new:
    for line in input_file:
        if line.startsiwth('@'):
            new.writelines(buff)
            buff = []
        if line.startswith('/'):
            buff = []
            continue
        buff.append(line)
```

This is saves a buffer for lines and each time a `@` is encountered - the buffer is flushed to the file. On the other hand, when a `/` is encountered - the buffer is reset. Might need some work on edge cases but that's to give you an idea.

Comment: I didnt know it could work on large file without loop. So i didnt try this option.

Comment: @ShalomMak check my edit for large files that can't be read at once

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this you are looking for?

```
file = "a.log"
data=[]
with open(file) as input_data:
    # loops through the whole file
    for line in input_data:
        line2= line.rstrip('\n')
        if line2.startswith('@') and line2.endswith('/'):
            pass
        else:
          print(line)
          data.append(line)
print(data)
```

Comment: There is not one line in OP's example that starts with a `@` and ends with a `/`. From his expected output it seems he meant to remove all lines **between** a line starting with `@` and the next one starting with `/`

Comment: If I can quote what OP said:  ' I wanted to remove lines that start with '@' and end with '/' '
And in base of that I gave my code interpretation.

Comment: Yes I understand that, you can also see my comment to the question. But according to the example, this is not accurate

Comment: BTW, if you're going by that quote it should be `if line2.startswith('@') and line2.endswith('/'):`, not `or`

Comment: That is actually a good point!

Answer (score 0):

In your question you said you wanted to remove lines that start with '@' and end with '/' but your file doesn't contain any lines like this? If that's what you wanted to do then the code below should work and will create a newfile with all the lines meeting the set criteria (i.e starting with '@' and ending with '/') removed.

```
file = 'thefile.txt'
newfile = 'thenewfile.txt'
data = []

with open(file, 'r') as rf, open(newfile, 'w') as wf:
    for line in rf:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line.startswith('@') and not line.endswith('/'):
            data.append(line)
    for line in data:
        wf.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: There is not one line in OP's example that starts with a `@` and ends with a `/`. From his expected output it seems he meant to remove all lines **between** a line starting with `@` and the next one starting with `/`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below code:

```
with open('blah.log') as f:
  lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
  with open('blah1.log','w') as f1:
    for line in lines:
      if len(line) > 0 and line[0] == '@' and line[-1] == '/':
        continue
      else:
        f1.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: There is not one line in OP's example that starts with a `@` and ends with a `/`. From his expected output it seems he meant to remove all lines **between** a line starting with `@` and the next one starting with `/`

Comment: what i mean is, if the line start with @, for an example ' @30-SEP-20  10:42:51 ' then it will start to write the lines into a list. Then when the for line loop, loop to a line that starts with ' " ' , for an example ' "30-SEP-20 10:43:06 ' it will stop the loop and then it will write the list to a new file but if it loop to a line that starts with ' / ' , for an example ' /30-SEP-20 10:43:06 ' it will stop the loop and reset the list and then start over.Like what i coded.

Comment: You can see that i have 3 loops.The second and the third loop is to find what i want and what i dont want.Then, the first loop is to repeat the second and third loop

Comment: @ShalomMak Maybe you should create a new question where you will explain again what you are looking for.